# Did Apple already solve these issues in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, xcode4

For me downloading and installing Xcode 4 is a big deal. So hopefully someone can answer these questions:

When I tried the first version of Xcode 4, it had these problems. Are they solved now?

- Documentation Browser was broken
- cmd + Enter for Build&Run did not work. Instead it forced me to do it in two steps. I Build&Run hundreds of times per day.
- It hat trouble with importing frameworks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here awnser to your points.

- Documentation works fine here
- CMD + R Builds and Runs it for me
- Framework importing is very easy, and with 4.2 they made it more easy actually.

Edit:
CMD + Enter, puts your editor in standard view mode. It doesn't do anything with building or running your application.